# Axios posting empty request

Tags: node.js, axios

I am trying to send an `axios` request to the backend, but it ends up having an empty `body`, and i do not understand why it does that.
This is the code for the request:

```
axios.post('/register', {email: email, password: password, username: username, company: company}).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

And this is the code for the backend:

```
authRouter.post('/register', (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.body);

});
```

And this one outputs an empty `request.body`. I've also checked the `JSON` sent, and it is not empty at all. Is there a way to see what is the form of the request before being sent?
This `authRouter` is a `module.export`, that is being used by the main `app` module. This `app` module has this configuration:

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(session({ secret: "shh", resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(authRouter);

https.createServer({key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/key.pem'), cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/cert.pem')}, app).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Are you using [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) properly?

Comment: Do you have JSON parsing middleware?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question to include `app` configuration.

Comment: I'm guessing that the `body-parser` might be the issue, since on another occasion, I was using this module without `urlencoded` part, and I had no problem.

Comment: Or an `axios` header problem. I see that I should use `Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but isn't this `axios` default?

Comment: This is the issue indeed.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The issue came from the fact that `body-parser` wants an `x-www-form-urlencoded` request, and I wasn't providing one.

I've set the header for the axios request to it, and the code looks like this:

```
axios.post('/register', {
  email: email,
  password: password,
  username: username,
  company: company
}, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
```

Answer (score 7):

in my case I declare "Content-Type": "application / json" in the axios headers. For ease, I declare in the global attribute of axios.

in this way

```
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

Now its works

Answer (score 5):

To resolve my problem, I was been constraint to do essentially this

```
let config = {
               headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               } 
          }

let params = new UrlSearchParam();
    params.append('var1', 'val1');
    params.append('var2', 'val2');

//Finally

axios.post('gotourl', params, config).then( ( response ) => {
      console.log(response.data);
});
```

[More informations](https://github.com/axios/axios#user-content-using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format)

Answer (score 4):

You can use qs to serialize your payload.

Install: `npm i qs`

```
const qs = require('qs');
axios.post('/post/submit-timesheet', qs.stringify({your: 'data'}))
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've stack in same issue just now, and the problem in my case is in **transformRequest** function: it return data without JSON.stringifying it. That's how transformRequest func shoul looks like (logger in my case, using TypeScript):

```
const requestLogger = <D>(url: string, methodName: string) => (data: D): string => {
    console.log(`Request ${methodName} ${url}\n Body:,`, data)
    return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

and finally my post static method looks like so:

```
static baseHeaders: Object = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };

static post<T, B>({
        url,
        body,
        params = {},
        headers = {},
        needThrowError = false,
    }: IPost<B>): Promise<void | AxiosResponse<T>> {
        const rest = axios.create({
            params,
            baseURL: this.baseUrl,
            headers: {...this.baseHeaders, ...headers},
            timeout: TIMEOUT,
            transformRequest: requestLogger<B>(url, 'POST'),
            transformResponse: responseLogger<T>(url, 'POST'),
        })

        return rest.post(
            url,
            body,
        ).catch((error) => {
            defaultNetworkErrorHandler(error);
            if (needThrowError) {
                throw error;
            }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let data = qs.stringify(
              {
              username:this.username,
              password:this.password
          }
          )
          
          axios.post(`${this.$store.state.backendHost}/register`,data,
          {
              headers:{
                   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
              }
          })
```

This is the final version of code that I ended up with. Not using qs.stringify()
resulted in output something like that :
`{ '{"username":"shelly","password":"hell"}': '' }`
which is not desirable.
Another thing is You can use "postman" for generating the code[image]

I hope this will help, Im new to stackoverflow. so ignore if there's any mistake

Answer (score 0):

Then problem in my case was that my nodeJS server needed to parse the incoming JSON payload with the express.json() middleware.
I put this code in my main `index.js` file:

`app.use(express.json());`

And it fixed it.