# Axios POST to Node Trouble

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm using Axios to POST React state data to a node server.  My React constructor looks like:

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            formFields: {
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                dateOfBirth: '',
                username: '',
                password: ''
            }
        }
    }
```

My submitHandler:

```
    submitHandler = (e) => {
        const stateData = this.state;
        console.log(stateData)
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3002/api/posts',
            data: this.state
        })
    }
```

Here's my Node/Express handler:

```
app.post('/api/posts', (req, res) => {
    console.log('got here');
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200)
});
```

if I change the Axios data to a single element of the state, say this.state.formFields.firstName, the Node server receives the data and prints to console no problem.  But when I try to send the entire this.state object, I cannot log the data on the node end.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```js
submitHandler = (e) => {
        const stateData = this.state;
        console.log(stateData)
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3002/api/posts',
            data: {...this.state}
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with the following post:

[Axios posting empty request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143730/axios-posting-empty-request)

To summarize, you need to add the correct headers to the Axios POST.  The following change to the submit handler fixed the issue:

```
   submitHandler = (e) => {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3002/api/posts',
            data: this.state,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
    }
```