# Can't send data through axios, React and node back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await, axios

I'm trying to use axios to hit the back-end, it seems like something is off with the code structure because in the back-end when I try to console.log req.body I get undefined
here is my fron-end code:

```
const response = yield axios({
      url: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data: {
        baseLocation: baseLocation,
        atLocation: atLocation,
        departureDate: depatureDate,
        airline: airline,
      },
    });
```

Note: don't worry about the yield keyword, it's because I'm using redux-saga.

things I have tried:
I have tried to console.log `req.data` and `req.body` I got undefined.

when I try to `console.log(req)`
I get

```
req:  <ref *2> IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: true,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: false,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: true,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
  },
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { end: [Function: clearRequestTimeout] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: <ref *1> Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },       
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
      data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
      error: [Function: socketOnError],
      close: [Array],
      drain: [Function: bound socketOnDrain],
      resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
      pause: [Function: onSocketPause]
    },
    _eventsCount: 8,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 5
    },
    _server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 5
    },
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': [Function: bound setRequestTimeout],
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '2': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '3': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '4': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '5': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
      '6': [Function: bound onParserTimeout],
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [Circular *1],
      incoming: [Circular *2],
      outgoing: null,
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: true,
      onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
      [Symbol(resource_symbol)]: [HTTPServerAsyncResource]
    },
    on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: ServerResponse {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: false,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: true,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: false,
      _headerSent: false,
      socket: [Circular *1],
      _header: null,
      _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
      _sent100: false,
      _expect_continue: false,
      req: [Circular *2],
      locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 9,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      _consumed: true,
      [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
  },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: {
    host: 'localhost:3000',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'content-length': '0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36',    
    origin: 'http://localhost:3001',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    referer: 'http://localhost:3001/',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8'
  },
  rawHeaders: [
    'Host',
    'localhost:3000',
    'Connection',
    'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length',
    '0',
    'sec-ch-ua',
    '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'Accept',
    'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile',
    '?0',
    'User-Agent',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36',
    'Origin',
    'http://localhost:3001',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site',
    'same-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode',
    'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest',
    'empty',
    'Referer',
    'http://localhost:3001/',
    'Accept-Encoding',
    'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language',
    'en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8'
  ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  aborted: false,
  upgrade: false,
  url: '/search',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  statusMessage: null,
  client: <ref *1> Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },       
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
      data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
      error: [Function: socketOnError],
      close: [Array],
      drain: [Function: bound socketOnDrain],
      resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
      pause: [Function: onSocketPause]
    },
    _eventsCount: 8,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 5
    },
    _server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 5
    },
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': [Function: bound setRequestTimeout],
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '2': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '3': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '4': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '5': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
      '6': [Function: bound onParserTimeout],
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [Circular *1],
      incoming: [Circular *2],
      outgoing: null,
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: true,
      onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
      [Symbol(resource_symbol)]: [HTTPServerAsyncResource]
    },
    on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: ServerResponse {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: false,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: true,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: false,
      _headerSent: false,
      socket: [Circular *1],
      _header: null,
      _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
      _sent100: false,
      _expect_continue: false,
      req: [Circular *2],
      locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 9,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      _consumed: true,
      [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
  },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  next: [Function: next],
  baseUrl: '',
  originalUrl: '/search',
  _parsedUrl: Url {
    protocol: null,
    slashes: null,
    auth: null,
    host: null,
    port: null,
    hostname: null,
    hash: null,
    search: null,
    query: null,
    pathname: '/search',
    path: '/search',
    href: '/search',
    _raw: '/search'
  },
  params: {},
  query: {},
  res: <ref *3> ServerResponse {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: true,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: false,
    _headerSent: false,
    socket: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *3],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 9,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: null,
    _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
    _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
    _sent100: false,
    _expect_continue: false,
    req: [Circular *2],
    locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      'x-powered-by': [Array],
      'access-control-allow-origin': [Array]
    }
  },
  body: {},
  route: Route {
    path: '/search',
    stack: [ [Layer] ],
    methods: { post: true }
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
}
```

Comment: what happens if you just log out `req`?

Comment: @Anastazy await is built on top of yield, don't worry about async requests it works as expected here. I'm talking about the back end

Comment: @SamPetering I will edit my question

Comment: I would assume it's some config issue with your backend code rather than the front end--everything looks fine to me on the fe. I found this other issue that might be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143730/axios-posting-empty-request

Comment: actually, I had to stringify the data before sending it to the back-end, Thx for your help, buddy

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
I had to do it like so:

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
    baseLocation: baseLocation,
    atLocation: atLocation,
    departureDate: depatureDate,
    airline: airline,
  });
  try {
    const response = yield axios({
      url: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data: data,
    });

    console.log('response: ', response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('errasfd: ', err);
  }
```